# Formating a data form perl::DBI query

Tags: perl

I have a script that downloads data from a database.
But I am having trouble formatting the data into rows.

```
#!/perl/bin/perl
use FOOConf;
FOOConf::makeDBConnection(production);
$dbh=$EVTConf::dbh;
use Data::Dumper ;
my %extend_hash = %{@_[0]};
my $query = "select level_id,e_risk_symbol,e_exch_dest,penny,specialist from etds_extend";
if(!$dbh) {
    print "Error connecting to DataBase; $DBI::errstr\n";
    }
my $cur_msg = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "\n\nCould not prepare statement: ".$dbh->errstr;
$cur_msg->execute();
my (@row);
while (@row = $cur_msg->fetchrow_array ) {
    #foreach $row(@row) {
    #print "$row \n" ;
    printf "%-8s %-4s %-2s %-2s %-2s\n ", $row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4], $row[5];
    #printf "%-12s  %6.2f\n", $row[0], $row[3];
    #for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@row); $i++) {
    #    printf "%-12s  = %s\n", $cur_msg->{NAME}[$i], $row[$i];
    #    }
    #}
}
```

i am using this to format the rows. The format is all mesed up

```
printf "%-8s %-4s %-2s %-2s %-2s\n ", $row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3],
```

this is what the format is :

```
5        MRO  CS   1    0
 5        FFIV CS   1    0
 5        GM   CS   1    0
 5        MCP  CS   1    0
 5        RVBD CS   1    0
 6        OIS_SPIN XISX 0    1
 6        CVEO XISX 0    1
 6        MRVL AMXO 0    1
 6        MRX  AMXO 0    1
 6        MS   XISX 0    1
 6        MTG  XISX 0    1
```

if I just use this loop

```
while (@row = $cur_msg->fetchrow_array ) {
    foreach $row(@row) {
    print "$row \n" ;
    }
}
```

each row gets printed out one line at a time - the thread starts with a 5 - which seems to screw up the formatting. How do i factor this out first 5 ?

```
[ walt]$ ./test_db_data_format.very_simple | head -20
5
MRO
CS
1
0
5
FFIV
CS
1
0
5
GM
CS
1
0
5
MCP
CS
1
0
```

when i use I this loop this format  - which is really nice.
That level id comes in at beginning without being attached to a symbol - screwing me up.

```
while (@row = $cur_msg->fetchrow_array ) {
    for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@row); $i++) {
        printf "%-12s  = %s\n", $cur_msg->{NAME}[$i], $row[$i];
        }
    }
```

This is the results with the rows from the data base:

```
LEVEL_ID      = 5
E_RISK_SYMBOL  = MRO
E_EXCH_DEST   = CS
PENNY         = 1
SPECIALIST    = 0
LEVEL_ID      = 5
E_RISK_SYMBOL  = FFIV
E_EXCH_DEST   = CS
PENNY         = 1
SPECIALIST    = 0
LEVEL_ID      = 5
E_RISK_SYMBOL  = GM
E_EXCH_DEST   = CS
PENNY         = 1
SPECIALIST    = 0
LEVEL_ID      = 5
```

What I need is the E_RISK_SYMBOL to start and a newline after LEVEL_ID to start a new row.
It should look just like this just like this:

```
MRO      CS   1 0 5
FFIV     CS   1 0 5
GM       CS   1 0 5
MCP      CS   1 0 5
RVBD     CS   1 0 6
OIS_SPIN XISX 0 1 6
```

Comment: Just remove the inner loop (i.e. `foreach $row(@row) {`).

Comment: thank you  - edited out the inner loop - I am having trouble withthe formatting of the data though

Comment: The original code sample is fine, except for the trailing space and the fact that you're trying to put data that's more than 4 characters wide in a 4-character column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your primary problem was just a trailing space in your format string after the `\n` and the fact that you were printing the `$row[0]` first instead of last.

You can also simplify your code by including the `my` declaration in the `while (COND)` and also using an array slice instead of listing out a bunch of individual array elements.

```
while (my @row = $cur_msg->fetchrow_array ) {
    printf "%-8s %-4s %-2s %-2s %-2s\n", @row[1..4,0];
}
```

Note: You were also passing 6 values to a format string with only 5 spots in your first code.  If you actually want the 6th variable to be displayed, you'll have to specify its format as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (@row = $cur_msg->fetchrow_array ) {
    printf "%-8s %-4s %-2s %-2s %-2s\n", $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4], $row[0];
}
```

Personally, I'd probably fetch it as a hashref to aide in making it more readable/understandable/maintainable.

```
while (my $row = $cur_msg->fetchrow_hashref ) {
    printf "%-8s %-4s %-2s %-2s %-2s\n", $row->{e_risk_symbol},
                                         $row->{e_exch_dest},
                                         $row->{penny},
                                         $row->{specialist},
                                         $row->{level_id};
}
```